# Pass pointers from java to C in JNI?

Tags: java, pointers, java-native-interface

i have a native method `char* getMinutae(char *imageName,int *len)` that takes `imageName` as input. It returns the template as buffer, length of this buffer is returned in (int *len). How do I pass the parameters for this method from java side?

Comment: Don't use a char*, use a jstring and jint, also, don't write yourself these functions but use the `javah` tool instead to generate this stuff from the java file, it will be a lot easier.

Comment: Thanks Uraimo. I have generated this function using javah tool. How do I pass the parameters for this method from java side?

Comment: In that example you didn't use javah, the type are wrong. On java side you should have a `native getMinutae(String imageName, int len);` , use that. To return a String, you need to build a jstring and return that, look here: https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaNativeInterface.html

Comment: The C type system is anemic. Please fully describe the parameters and return value, including (if applicable) the character set and encoding of strings ("platform default" can be sufficient), terminator or count/size, and memory allocation and freeing responsibilities.